# How Do I get a search Bar to Search

Tags: html, css

I was programming my first website, using css and html and I found a custom search bar that looks cool and I got it to work in the layout of my website, problem is whenever I try to search something it moves me to a blank page with text that says "not found". How do I make the search bar work?

I below I have listed the website I used for my css for the search bar which works fine, and I listed the div I put the html for my searchbar

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous" >

<div id="searchbar>
 <form action="">
  <input type="search">
  <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
 </form>
</div>
```

I want to be able to search my website with it.
(please do keep in mind that this is my first few months of programming so I know very little, I appreciate the help but not the criticism)

Comment: You need a database to search data from and need php to process the search

Comment: You think that adding an input with a search icon will _somehow_ make it to be a search engine on your website? Because it doesn't work this way

Comment: [Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You have to bring logic into your project. HTML and CSS have no logic.

Comment: You can use [google custom search](https://cse.google.com/cse/) for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As some of the comments inferred it requires a little more than just adding an input field to your website to have search functionality. Depending on what type of site you're building there are different solutions out there.

Since you're just beginning I'd recommend looking into Google's [Custom Search Engine](https://cse.google.com/cse/). They allow you to embed a search form on your site, which will search through the contents of your site for you.

If you're interested in doing something more custom then you will need to post more details about the project you're doing. Is it a WordPress site, just plain HTML/CSS/JS, are you using a framework to build on, etc.

Comment: Thank you very much, I am very inexperienced as you may tell, but very helpful nonetheless.

Comment: Glad I could help, don't pay attention to the trolls. Keep with it, asking questions is how you learn.